# Ruby on Rails - Pass item selected from a Javascript dropdown to Rails controller when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, controller

- I have a button right next to a dropdown
- When a user selects a value from the dropdown and clicks on the button, the value from the dropdown should be passed as a parameter to the Rails controller function
- This is the code that I'm using:

  `<%= link_to 'Generate Report', forecast_report_pdf_path(format: :pdf), onclick: "GetSelectedItem('select1')", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>`
- how do I pass the value returned by the GetSelectedItem function to my controller? (I already pass format = pdf as a parameter now; but I am not sure how to pass the value returned by GetSelectedItem as well)

Comment: Put your control in a form and make the button a submit button.  Clicking on the button will then post all the current value of the control to your controller. You'll just need to have the route and controller action set up. For examples, see https://launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-rails/writing-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%= form_tag forecast_report_pdf_path do %>
 <%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select([["Summary1", 7], ["Summary2", 6]])) %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
 <%= submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
```

I finally got around to writing the above code and it worked!! Thanks much for your inputs @nicolasnisoria !

Answer (score 2):

I don't if this is the best solution but you could use a form inside the dropdown so you select the option and the value is sent to the controller.

Here you have an example but feel free to adapt it to your code:

```
<%= form_for :pdf, url: forecast_report_pdf_path(format: :pdf) |form| %>
  <%= select_tag(:person, :city_id, [['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...]) %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.submit 'Generate Report', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end  %>
```

Check rails documentation for more details: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html